# Unzip .zip on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, zip, unzip

I've updated to 15.10 from 15.04. My laptop has a pre-installed Ubuntu since I bought it.

Every time I try to open a .zip file, this error message shows:
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgVYv.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you try to open another .zip file?
What if you test the archive? `gunzip -t filename.zip`?

Comment: Opening another .zip has the same problem

Comment: try simple unzip then, like this: `unzip -t yourfile.zip`. In my case it prints out: `$ unzip -t a.zip 
Archive:  a.zip
    testing: bb                       OK
No errors detected in compressed data of a.zip.`

Comment: Did you do this `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full` ? You need this package to unpack zip files.

Comment: How do I enter the name? the file's name is Snow Leopard Wallpapers. How do I type this in terminal?

Comment: Typing names containing spaces in terminal is little tricky. Use the advantage of TAB to complete the word. So you start typing **unzip -t Sno** (yes, just that) and then you press TAB - terminal shell should automatically complete the filename for you.

For the sake of testing-only, you might rename the file to something easy as "aaa.zip"

PS: the **-t** parameter means unzip tests the archive integrity

Comment: Install `p7zip` with `sudo apt-get install p7zip`. To extract type: `p7zip -d <filename>.zip`. If you still get error, install `p7zip-full` with `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full`. Use the same command for extraction.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is with the GUI, right click on the file you want to open and choose "Open With" option, scroll down to p7zip, if installed, and use that option.
If P7zip, or whatever you use, DOES NOT appear, you'll have to search for it by opening a terminal and entering 'whereis p7zip'.
Go back to 'Open With', choose other and go to the above directory and choose p7zip, make it the default option, and proceed.